# App crash with error: Unable to find JSIModule for class UIManager, after touch event on ad

Tags: react-native, crash, admob, ads, uimanager

I've created a component to show ads in my react-native app using `react-native-admob-native-ads`.
It's running perfectly on most of the app screens, but on some screens, the app crashes just after the touch event on the ad,
I don't understand the issue as it is fine on most of the screens, and the same component is used everywhere

This is the crash log

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find JSIModule for class UIManager
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModuleRegistry.getModule(JSIModuleRegistry.java:24)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getJSIModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:564)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:90)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:46)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManagerForReactTag(UIManagerHelper.java:40)
        at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.handleEvent(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:505)
        at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.onEventDispatch(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:483)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcherImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatcherImpl.java:116)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.JSTouchDispatcher.handleTouchEvent(JSTouchDispatcher.java:74)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.dispatchJSTouchEvent(ReactRootView.java:283)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.onInterceptTouchEvent(ReactRootView.java:201)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2635)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2724)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1853)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4059)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:454)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13749)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5635)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5435)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4936)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4989)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4955)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5095)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4963)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5152)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4936)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4989)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4955)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4963)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4936)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7688)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7657)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7618)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7816)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:251)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31245) in React Native 0.64.0. Someone is looking into it: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31245#issuecomment-811587180
It's also discussed in [upcoming v0.64.1 cherrypicks](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/issues/221#issuecomment-808059427), so there is a possibility that it will be fixed in the next version. In the meantime it can be fixed by downgrading React Native to 0.63.4.

Comment: Another potential workaround is to downgrade specific UI component libraries, such as `react-native-tab-view`, in order to use `react-native 0.64.0`.