# Unable to find JSIModule for class UIManager at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModuleRegistry.getModule(JSIModuleRegistry.java:24)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Current behavior
React Native ANDROID app is crashing. (I have 4 tabs)

After tapping on two or more tabs quickly, it causes React Native ANDROID app to crash.
here is the log i find on Android studio im using  "react-navigation/bottom-tabs version": "^6.0.9", and "react-native version": "^0.64.1",
--------- beginning of crash
2021-12-15 20:05:56.380 24153-24153/com.letzwork.letzwork E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.letzwork.letzwork, PID: 24153
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find JSIModule for class UIManager
at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModuleRegistry.getModule(JSIModuleRegistry.java:24)
at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getJSIModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:564)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:90)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:46)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManagerForReactTag(UIManagerHelper.java:40)
at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.handleEvent(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:505)
at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedNodesManager.onEventDispatch(NativeAnimatedNodesManager.java:483)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcherImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatcherImpl.java:116)
at com.facebook.react.uimanager.JSTouchDispatcher.handleTouchEvent(JSTouchDispatcher.java:74)
at com.facebook.react.views.modal.ReactModalHostView$DialogRootViewGroup.onInterceptTouchEvent(ReactModalHostView.java:497)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2753)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3222)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2845)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:697)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1879)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchTouchEvent(Dialog.java:1004)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:655)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13736)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6116)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5894)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5343)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5396)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5362)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5521)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5578)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5343)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:5396)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5362)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5370)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:5343)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8405)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:8338)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8291)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:8520)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:198)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7073)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:964)

Comment: Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66938864/8196025)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App crash with error: Unable to find JSIModule for class UIManager, after touch event on ad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65559549/app-crash-with-error-unable-to-find-jsimodule-for-class-uimanager-after-touch)